# Spring kafka manual offset commit does not work as expected

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

In my kafka consumer application, configurations are as below and I am using spring kafka version 2.8.

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConfig.getBootStrapServer());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, CONSUMER_GROUP_ID);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, MAX_POLL_RECORDS);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
```

kafka listner container factory is configured as below and I am using **MANUAL_IMMEDIATE** acknowledgement.

```
@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, Order_Response>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() throws SSMUtilFailedException {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, Order_Response> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.INFO);
    return factory;
}
```

My kafkalistner would look like this. Here I manaully acknowledge all the consumed records.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = KAFKA_CONSUME_TOPIC)
public void listenForOrderResponses(ConsumerRecord<Integer, record> consumedRecord, Acknowledgment ack){
  ack.acknowledge();}
```

**When I forcefully crash (JVM) consumer application and start it again, the consumer does not fetch records from the last committed offset. It misses some of the messages and the offset has increased. I want to consume from the last committed offset.** Could you please tell me what is missing here?

Comment: How do you know that you consumed for the last committed offset? Before you started the app again, had you checked the last committed offset that your app had committed?

Comment: actually, in my real application, i have logged all the offsets. so when I forcefully crash the JVM I know what is the last committed offset by using     'factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.INFO)'. This will log committed offsets.

Comment: when a consumer re-joins an existing `ConsumerGroup`, it will start polling at the latest committed offset so far of assigned partitions. That's why I wondered if your app had committed some offsets before it crashed.

Comment: Also, I am observing the same issue for "MANUAL" acknowledgment mode. Here i have set MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG to 10.
When consuming from offset 0 to 10 in the first poll and if I crash application at offset 5, after re-starting consumer application will start consuming from offset 10. Lost 5-10 messages

Comment: What you are suggesting makes no sense; please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits this behavior.